# Too many input arguments wit fmincon in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization

I'm playing with Matlab `fmincon` function but I think I don't get how to make it work properly.

I need to optimize the value of two parameters: `err1` and `err2` acting on one parameter `param_1`, in order to find the value of `param_1` that allow to `err1` and `err2` to reach the ideal parameters `ideal1` and `ideal2`

The two ideal parameters are known. To compute `err1` and `err2` I use two functions that are basically the same, one with output `err1` and the other give `err2` as output.

Before the optimisation I have a single function giving as output the two parameters and I compute the distance that I will use as constrain

```
ideal1 = [0;0.3536;0.0000;-0.3536;-0.5000;-0.3536;-0.0000;0.3536;0.5000];
ideal2 = [0;0.3536;0.5000;0.3536;0.0000;-0.3536;-0.5000;-0.3536;-0.0000];
err1 = [0;0.1750;-0.1167;-0.2917;-0.3500;-0.1750;0.1167;0.3500;0.3500];
err2 = [0;0.2917;0.2917;0.1750;-0.1167;-0.2917;-0.2917;-0.1167;0.1167];
ideal_distance = sum(sqrt(ideal1.^2+ideal2.^2))
real_distance = sum(sqrt(err1.^2+err2.^2))
```

I think that the problem is the number of input parameters in these two functions: 20 input parameters, where most of them are scalar values and some of them are matrices, files, etc...

```
err1 = @(param_1) compute_err1_funct(param_1,param_2,param_3,...,param_20);
err2 = @(param_1) compute_err2_funct(param_1,param_2,param_3,...,param_20);
```

Then I need two other functions to transform the two `err1`,`err2` in the two values that I need:

```
err1_convert = @(param_1) transf_funct(  -7 inputs-  )
err2_convert = @(param_1) transf_funct(  -7 inputs-  )
```

and finally I try to find the optimum result

```
param_1 = [1,2]
fmincon(err1_convert,param_1,real_distance,ideal_distance)
```

Here I get the error

> Too many input arguments.

that propagates inside `fmincon`

> Error in fmincon (line 546)
>         initVals.f = feval(funfcn{3},X,varargin{:});
>
> Caused by:
>       Failure in initial objective function evaluation. FMINCON cannot continue.

Comment: Yes I know but this is the best I can do. I basically need that (`err1_convert`,`err2_convert`) become as close as possible to (`ideal1`,`ideal1`)  acting on one of the many parameters. I read in the internet that the problem could be the limitation to 10 input parameters to `fmincon` and if this is solvable collecting the input parameters somehow or if I'm not giving to fmincon the correct arguments that he needs

Answer (score 0):

(1) Your error is probably caused by some mistake in the definition of "err1_convert", possibly in the definition of the "transf_funct" function which you didn't specify here. Make sure the number of input variables in the definition of the function and when it is called is exactly the same.

.

(2) It is probably not the reason for this specific error, but there is another thing you need to fix to avoid (a different) error: your parameter is a vector of length 2, and therefore if you add to [fmincon](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) the 3rd and 4th parameters (A and b), then A ("real_distance") needs to be a 2x2 matrix, and b (ideal_distance) needs to be a vector of length 2 (while according to the code, they are both scalars).If `A = [a11,a12 ; a21,a22]` and `b = [b1;b2]` then the restrictions are: `a11*x1 + a12*x2 <= b1` and `a21*x1 + a22*x2 <= b2`.

If you meant "real_distance" and "ideal_distance" to be lower and upper bounds, you should have written (assuming: real_distance < ideal_distance):

```
fmincon(err1_convert, param_1, [], [], [], [], real_distance, ideal_distance)
```

Since lb and ub (lower and upper bound) are the 7th and 8th parameters in fmincon, not the 3rd and 4th.